# C# parse & compare huge list/string

Tags: c#, string, list, parsing, compare

I have 2 giant lists (over 2000 each)

And I want to parse & compare them.

What the list looks like:

```
zone "exampledomain.com" {
zone "exampledomain2.com" {
zone "exampledomain3.com" {
zone "exampledomain4.com" {
zone "exampledomain5.com" {
zone "exampledomain6.com" {
zone "exampledomain7.com" {
```

What the other list looks like:

```
zone "exampledomain.com" {
zone "exampledomain3.com" {
zone "exampledomain5.com" {
zone "exampledomain7.com" {
```

Both lists have this same format of zone "____" {
I want to parse so that I can compare the domains and then get the difference of domains so I know what the other one is missing, they should both have the same results.

I have come across this code:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s1 = "i have a car a car";
    string s2 = "i have a new car bmw";

    List<string> diff;
    IEnumerable<string> set1 = s1.Split(' ').Distinct();
    IEnumerable<string> set2 = s2.Split(' ').Distinct();

    if (set2.Count() > set1.Count())
    {
        diff = set2.Except(set1).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        diff = set1.Except(set2).ToList();
    }
}
```

But I am wondering what would be the best way to do it considering I have over 2000 lines in each list.

Answer (score 0):

The example you give will only show list 1 with the items from list 2 removed. If you also want what is in list 2 that isn't in list 1 you will have to do two queries

```
var difference1 = list1.Except(list2);
var difference2 = list2.Except(list1);
```

I'm not sure what code is involved when Except is executed, but if you'd like to see an implementation of how to generate two lists containing differences then here is one solution:

```
static void Differerence(
  IEnumerable<string> source1, IEnumerable<string> source2, 
  out List<string> difference1, out List<string> difference2)
{
    //Move the data from the sources into ordered queues
    var sourceValues1 = new Queue<string>(source1.OrderBy(x => x));
    var sourceValues2 = new Queue<string>(source2.OrderBy(x => x));

    difference1 = new List<string>();
    difference2 = new List<string>();

    while(sourceValues1.Count > 0 && sourceValues2.Count > 0)
    {
        string value1 = sourceValues1.Peek();
        string value2 = sourceValues2.Peek();
        switch (string.Compare(value1, value2))
        {
            //If they match then don't add difference to either list
            case 0:
                sourceValues1.Dequeue();
                sourceValues2.Dequeue();
                break;

            //The left queue has the lowest value, record that and move on
            case -1:
                difference1.Add(value1);
                sourceValues1.Dequeue();
                break;

            //The right queue has the lowest value, record that and move on
            case 1:
                difference2.Add(value2);
                sourceValues2.Dequeue();
                break;

        }
    }
    //At least one of the queues is empty, so everything left in the other queue
    difference1.AddRange(sourceValues1);
    difference2.AddRange(sourceValues2);
}
```

I don't know how LINQ could possibly do it any faster, but my routine will deal with duplicates entries like the value "1" in the following example, whereas LINQ won't. So keep that in mind when choosing which to use rather than just the difference in speed.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list1 = new string[] { "1", "1", "3", "5", "7", "9" };
    var list2 = new string[] { "1", "2", "4", "6", "9", "10" };

    var difference1 = list1.Except(list2);
    var difference2 = list2.Except(list1);

    List<string> differenceX1;
    List<string> differenceX2;

    Differerence(list1, list2, out differenceX1, out differenceX2);
}
```

It's easy to combine the two results into one if you need to

```
var allDifferences = differenceX1.Union(differenceX2);
```

Answer (score -1):

HashSets are used for lists of unique elements:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx

```
HashSet<string> uniqueStrings = new HashSet<string>();

foreach (string s1 in list1)
{
    uniqueStrings.Add(s1);
}

foreach (string s2 in list2)
{
    uniqueStrings.Add(s2);
}
```